# Formula when index of sigma is negative

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

We're currently learning series and sigma notation

We've been given the formulas for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$, and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$ plus the properties on how to break them apart etc, place the constant c in front and multiply by the resulting sum.

Now I've been given $\sum_{k=-1}^{5}k^2$  and I'm stuck because the formulas won't work for that.  If k=2 I understand that I can do $\sum_{k=1}^{5}k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{1}k^2$ but that same concept won't work when k=-1

Is there a formula to solve it or is it just a matter of multiplying it all out

Comment: Pull out the $n=-1$ and $n=0$ terms.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't write $\sum_{n = 1}^n n$ because it's meaningless; $n$ means a different thing in two different places, so you ought to have $\sum_{k = 1}^n k = \frac{k(k + 1)}{2}$. Secondly, try writing out the terms; break the positive terms and negative terms into separate parts.

Comment: @T.Bongers thanks, fixed the notation.   So you're saying $\sum_{k=1}^{5}k^2 - \sum_{k=-1}^{0}k^2$ ?

Comment: No, because it's $\sum_{k = 1}^5 k^2 + \sum_{k = -1}^0 k^2$.

Comment: Taking pre-calc after about 15 years since my last math class, it's all slowly coming back

Comment: @T.Bongers Ah yes that makes sense.  Is that how it's generally done?  The book doesn't even list the formulas for $k^2$ or $k^3$ let alone negative indexes.  However, the worksheet we were assigned from a different text has more complicated examples

Comment: @T.Bongers if you create an answer I'll accept it, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Hint:** We have
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=-1}^5k^2}&=(-1)^2+0^2+1^2+\cdots+5^2\\
> &=\sum_{k=-1}^0k^2+\sum_{k=1}^5k^2\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1+\sum_{k=1}^5k^2}\\
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I give you below the general formulae
$$\sum_{k=m}^{n}k=\frac{1}{2} (n-m+1) (n+m)$$
$$\sum_{k=m}^{n}k^2=\frac{1}{6} (n-m+1) \left(2 m^2+2 m n-m+2 n^2+n\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=m}^{n}k^3=\frac{1}{4} (n-m+1) (m+n) \left(m^2-m+n^2+n\right)$$

Comment: I know the formulas for these, the issue is when m = -1 or -m is where I was having an issue.